# Google Sheets: How do you combine several sets of data into a single table?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to import data from Athletic.net and create a table that includes values over several years of athletics.

I have successfully used ImportHTML to import 3 seperate tables. One for the each of the 3 most recent years.

I am trying to combine all of the like events into one table. Unfortunately the way they get imported does not make that easy. The fist columns of each table look like this (each table also includes athlete names, grade, and times. Not included here):

| EVENT 2023 | EVENT 2022 | EVENT 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *100 meter* | *60 meter* | *100 meter* |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | *100 meter* | *200 meter* |
| *200 meter* | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | *400 meter* |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| *400 meter* | *200 meter* | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | *1600 meter* |

I want to combine them into:

| EVENT |
| --- |
| *60 meter* |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| *100 meter* |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| ... |

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data and desired output (manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture & also makes it easy for us to work it out...

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Maybe you could also share the importHtml formulas that you're using, that way we can see how the is imported and compared it to your expected output.